File Upload component not showing image from Laravel local driver in Filament
I'm using FilamentPHP in my Laravel project. I'm using: FILESYSTEM_DISK and FILAMENT_FILESYSTEM_DISK local for store the file in storage. I've laravel seeder which creates some records in my DB and store images into storage/app/tool_photo_path folder. When I try to edit the tool then FileUpload component shows broken image, you can see attached image. I want to show image while edit the tool. When I use the public disk then it working fine but I want to use local driver.
Image
I'm using below code for file upload as per filament built-in feature:
FileUpload::make('tool_photo_path')
                ->label('Tool photo')
                ->image()
                ->directory('tool_photo_path')
                ->required(),

Here my DB column name is tool_photo_path and folder name is also same. Now anyone can tell me how can I see uploaded image after refresh the page.
I've try with visibility feature given my Filament but nothing is working for me.

Make sure you've updated the APP_URL the url you're using for testing. For example if your app url on your .env file is localhost but your url in browser is localhost:8000 then the image isn't going to show. They have to match exactly. Also make you're you've run php artisan storage:link

Thanks for the reply but I've already mentioned that I used local driver instead of public.

Is anyone have idea about this?

I don't know your reason for not using whatever folder you decide in storage to store the images and link that folder to the public folder. that's how it's meant to be.
